# Search with regular expression in Sublime Text 2

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

I want to create a rule to remove `array(` and `)` from this text:

```
"price"=>     array(129),
```

to get:

```
"price"=>     129,
```

I tried this expression without success:

```
(?<="price"=>\s*)array\((?=\d*)\)(?=,)
```

Then I decided to made replacement in 2 steps. Firstly, I removed `array(`:

```
(?<="price"=>\s\s\s\s\s)array\(
```

And got:

```
"price"=>     129),
```

So I had to remove only a closing parenthesis `)`. I tried without success:

```
(?<="price"=>\s*\d*)\)(?=,)
```

This works, but only for a known number of whitespaces and digits:

```
(?<="price"=>\s\s\s\s\s\d\d\d)\)(?=,)
```

Comment: why dont you start using \s+ and \d+ ...?

Comment: @vault, `(?<="price"=>\s+\d+)\)(?=,)` doesn't work, too.

Comment: sure, it just hurts to see someone writing \s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s

Comment: @vault but \s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s works :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for the find:

`("price"=>\s+)array\((\d+)\)`

and this for the replace:

`\1\2`

Comment: The `\s+` should be replaced by `\s*` if spaces are not guaranteed to be present

Answer (score 1):

you can match whole line with this

```
\"price"[^a)]+(array\()\d+(\),)
```

it contains one group for "array(" and another for "),"

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, Sublime selects the whole line and I have to make replacements in selection to get `"price"=>     129,`. It is not very useful if there are a lot of files to perform this operation.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(?:(?<=\"price\"=>\s*)array\((?=\d+\)))|(?<=\"price\"=>\s*array\(\d+)\)
```

The regex consists mainly two parts (the pipe in the middle is an alternation symbol which means if the first part doesn't match it should look for the second part).

The first part checks if **array(** is preceded by **"price"=> ...** and is succeded by **)** by using the [look-behind](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php) **(?<= ... )** and [look-ahead](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php) **(?= ... )** symbol respectively.

```
(?:(?<=\"price\"=>\s*)array\((?=\d+\)))
```

Then we have a pipe (explained above)..

```
|
```

The second part checks if **)** is preceded by everything we've matched before (**"price"=>     array(129**) also using the [look-behind](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php) symbol **(<= ... )**:

```
(?<=\"price\"=>\s*array\(\d+)\)
```

Thus for the string **"price"=>     array(129),** the result should be two matches: **array(** and **)**.

Please let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, Sublime selects the whole line and I have to make replacements in selection to get `"price"=>     129,`. It is not very useful if there are a lot of files to perform this operation.

Comment: I haven't used Sublimetext before. Are you performing a "Find and Replace" action with regex?

Comment: In Sublime Text I can select text inside HTML tags (or any other patter) as shown in this [example](http://www.evernote.com/shard/s2/sh/69d3c95a-5e16-44ab-b43e-1bb76db221e6/4c86a1ac0b3d36c129f7640f7b44dbf9) and delete/replace it.

Comment: Thanks again. However, I think that there is a bug in Sublime—it doesn't find anything with `\s*` or `\d*` inside `(?<= )`.

Comment: OK, try to replace `\s*` with **[ \t\n]*** (notice the space inside the brackets) and `\d+` with **[0-9]+**

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work, too. @JamieJag solution works.